# Array from store updated even without any action with react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have section with 2 possible functionalities: if I click on some svg file on desktop, I show user small section with select elements. When I select some option, I update current object from store. In store i have also array of same objects. And for some mysterious reason related object in array also updates. Code for updating object in reducer:

```
case CHANGE_DAMAGE:
return {
  ...state,
  currentAdvert: {
    ...state.currentAdvert,
    condition: {
      ...action.condition
    }
  }
};
```

When I click cancel changes, and trying get same object but from array(which should content initial values), in this object data is same with the current one. In redux devtools there is no any additional action calls except my changeDamage, so there is my trouble point.
What can be issue for this weird behaviour?

UPD: my store structure is:

```
{allAdverts: [{}, ...]//array of objects

 currentAdvert: {
    ...//some fields,
  condition: {}//object which I change in reducer
 },//some object from allAdverts array
```

I using this object in render like this:

```
<BackLeftWing isDamaged={this.state.condition.exterior.rearWing.scratched || this.state.condition.exterior.rearWing.dented} />
```

Comment: couple of questions: 1) which object in this array does also update? 2) can you post the code where you use the object you are talking about? 3) do you modify the code somewhere else by any chance ?

Comment: @DoXicK added structure, in array same object updates as current one.
For second question: I use it as props for svg components for detecting damageg this car part or not(and change color).
For 3rd question: how can I modify store outside of reducer?

Comment: for an answer to 3) if you have a component where you do `this.state.condition.exterior.rearWing.scratched = true`, you just modified your store outside of a reducer

Comment: @DoXicK Thanks, dont know about it. Well, i found solution by writing big ugly function for cancel changes(store values for every car part in array and on click just replace current values in condition object by initial). But I still think there can be more elegant and "right" solution...